# Why is python choking on numpy.core.ma?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to set up pylab on my mac 10.6.7 32 bit machine; using virutalenv to isolate what I'm doing from everything else (coming from a ruby/rvm background this just makes me feel better--but I'm open to correction if it's not the "python way").

I have the following modules/libs installed:

```
DateUtils-0.5.1-py2.7.egg-info  numpy-1.5.1-py2.7.egg-info
IPython             pip-0.8.3-py2.7.egg
configobj.py            pylab.py
configobj.pyc           pylab.pyc
dateutil                pymc
dateutils               pymc-2.1beta-py2.7.egg-info
easy-install.pth            python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg-info
enthought               pytz
ipython-0.10.1-py2.7.egg-info   pytz-2011e-py2.7.egg-info
matplotlib              scipy
matplotlib-0.91.1-py2.7.egg-info    scipy-0.9.0-py2.7.egg-info
nose                setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
nose-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info       setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88795-py2.7.egg
numpy               setuptools.pth
```

The only one I can't account for is enthought; I have never installed their python solution -must be a dependency of something else.

Numpy appears to be working just fine, matplotlib can be imported without issue; both from a shell. When I call just plain ipython no trouble either. But when I try and use pylab I python chokes on numpy.core.ma as in:

```
File "/Users/davidbgonzalez/.virtualenvs/VirtPy27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/numerix/ma/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from numpy.core.ma import *
ImportError: No module named ma
```

Backing into this I opened the `__init__.py` and a prompt as alluded to [here](http://www.saiweb.co.uk/mac/matplotlib-importerror-no-module-named-ma). Sure enough, `ma` is found in `numpy.ma` not `numpy.core.ma`; verified via `import numpy.ma`.

I change the offending line:

```
from numpy.core.ma import * -> from numpy.ma import *
```

And get a new, very similar, error:

```
File "/Users/davidbgonzalez/.virtualenvs/VirtPy27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/numerix/npyma/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from numpy.core.ma import *
ImportError: No module named ma
```

But when I change that instance of `numpy.core.ma` to `numpy.ma` I get a dreadful:

```
Bus error
```

I'm open to any solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have a extremely old version of Matplotlib installed. I'm not sure where you got it, but the current version (1.0.1) can be downloaded from http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you. I think this is going to work. I got that dated version using `pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 8):

For someone else coming googling around, the one liner you search is currently:

```
pip install -U 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz/download'
```